# params[:search] error after updating to Rails 4.1

Tags: ruby, search, ruby-on-rails-4.1, mysql2

I recently updated my Rails app from 4.0 to 4.1. Everything seems to work fine, except this one line in my Resource_Tag Model that was working before.

Essentially, I want to search/find District_Resources by Tag Name and by the District_Resource Name.

```
**ex.**
If I search the word "Tutoring" 
*I should get all District_Resources with the Resource_Tag "Tutoring"
*And all District Resources that include the word Tutoring in it's Name. 
(i.e Tutoring Services)
```

For some reason, I keep getting this error:

```
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
all(:conditions =>  (string ? [cond_text, *cond_values] : []))
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
class ResourceTagsController < ApplicationController

  def index    
    if params[:search].present?

      #Calls Search Model Method
      @resource_tags = ResourceTag.search(params[:search])
      @tagsearch = ResourceTag.search(params[:search])
      @tag_counts = ResourceTag.count(:group => :name, 
        :order => 'count_all DESC', :limit => 100)
    else
      @resource_tags = ResourceTag.all
    end
  end

end
```

**MODELS**

```
class DistrictResource < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :district_mappings, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :resource_tags, through: :district_mappings

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :resource_tags
end

class ResourceTag < ActiveRecord::Base

  #create relationships with all resource and mapping models
  has_many :district_mappings, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :district_resources, through: :district_mappings

  #I GET AN ERROR HERE
  def self.search(string)
    return [] if string.blank?

    cond_text = string.split(', ').map{|w| "name like ?"}.join(" OR ")   

    cond_values = string.split(', ').map{|w| "%#{w}%"}

    all(:conditions =>  (string ? [cond_text, *cond_values] : []))
  end

end
```

**VIEWS**

```
<%= form_tag(resource_tags_path, :method => 'get', class: "navbar-search") do %>
  <form>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :class => "search-query form-control" %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil, :class => "search-button" %>
  </form>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Not enough for an answer, but in Rails 4, `all(conditions)` migth be deprecated. Whether or not, you should use `where(attr1: value, attr2: value)`

Comment: Can you tell me the value of `params[:search]` for which this error occures?

Comment: "search"=>"Mentoring, Tutoring"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After an hour search I came to know that In rails 4.1 onward `all` method of `ActiveRecord` does not take any parameters that's why extra argument error occurs. You can try `where` instead. Here is your search method

```
def search(string)

return [] if string.blank?

cond_text = string.split(', ').map{|w| "name like ?"}.join(" OR ")   

cond_values = string.split(', ').map{|w| "%#{w}%"}

self.where(string ? [cond_text, *cond_values] : [])

end
```

Comment: I am trying this, but for some reason it returns every value, just like saying self.all

Comment: What are you passing to `search` method as paramter?